# Google Spreasheet decrease value periodically

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to decrease a value in a cell periodically (e.g. decrease by 1 every day) and *only if the value is greater than zero*. Can you think of a solution to this problem?

Comment: Need more information to make it a good question. Do you need a formula solution, or a script? if formula, will it be applied to one cell or many? Should the script run automatically? What data are we operating on? etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A script would be better:

```
function countdowntimer() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var range = ss.getRange('Sheet1!A1'); //Get Sheet1 A1
var value = range. getValue();
if (value>0) {range.setValue(value-1);} //set a value lesser by 1,If >0
}
```

From the script editor, choose Edit > Current project's triggers.
Click the link that says: No triggers set up. Click here to add one now.
Under Run, select the name of function you want to trigger.
Under Events, select  Time-driven. Set it up for everyday.